# ADO.NET Pooled connections are unable to reuse

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, owin, connection-pooling

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application which use EF 6.x to work with my Azure SDL Database. Recently with an increased load app start to get into a state when it's unable to communicate with the SQL server anymore. I can see that there are 100 active connections to my database using `exec sp_who` and any new connection is unable to create with the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider
>   failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection
>   from the pool.  This may have occurred because of all pooled connections
>   were in use and max pool size was reached.

Most of the time app works with average active connection count from 10 to 20. And any load doesn't change this number... Event when load is high it stays at level 10-20. But in certain situations, it could just up to 100 in less than a minute without any ramp up time and this causes app state when all my requests are failing. All those 100 connection are in `sleeping` state and `awaiting command`.

The good part is I found a workaround which helped me to mitigate the issue - clear connection pool from the client side. I'm using `SqlCoonection.ClearAllPools()` and it instantly closing all the connections and `sp_who` shows me my regular 10-20 connection after that.

The bad part, I still don't know the root cause.

Just to clarify the app load is about `200-300` concurrent users, which generate `1000` requests per minute

With the great suggestion @DavidBrowne to track leaked connection with a simple pattern I was able to find leaked connections while configuring `Owin` engine

```
private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // here in create method I'm creating also a connection leak tracker
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => MyCoolDb.Create());
    ...
}
```

Basically with every request, `Owin` creates a connection and doesn't let it go and when the `WebAPI` load is increased I have troubles.

Could it be the real cause and I `Owin` smart enough to lazy create a connection when needed (using the function provided) and let it go when it was used?

Comment: Are you sure you are disposing Context correctly?

Comment: yes, all the connections are created in using() scope. Moreover with the same load app could work for several days, even weeks, and then suddenly get into failure state.

Comment: Have you ruled out just plain bottlenecks in your database, lock escalation and whatnot. Could it be a queue of requests waiting for a resource(s) that a long running process is hogging? Any index rebuilding or other maintenance going on during the connection buildup periods you are seeing?

Comment: How does your application obtain the connection string? Is it always the same? Including the user?

Comment: Are you sure that's not expected? Why don't you change the `max pool size` value in the connection string?

Comment: @RossBush I was unable to detect any bottlenecks, all the queries works blazingly fast, an api call takes no longer than 20 ms on avg, active database connections ~ 10, my connection pool is 200 but I could hardly go above 10 active (sp_who). No long running process, no period tasks on the database. It's somehow connected to app load but connections justs from 10 to 200 in 10 seconds while the load is evenly distributed over the time (hours).

Comment: @JohnWu yes, the only connection string, the only connection pool (all the parameters the same), the process is the same `using(var db = new MyDbContext()) { ... }`

Comment: @SimonMourier it's definitely not expected behavior, the number of active connections jumps from 10 to 200 in 10 seconds period. Let's say the app could handle 80% of a load having a number of active connections ~ 10 but once it reaches 100% I could experience a sudden jump to 200 connection during a 10 sec period once every hour or so.

Comment: If the system's is under heavy load, that not unusual. ASP.NET can run thousands of threads if needed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) and you can roughly count to one connection per thread, especially if you do a lot of async stuff. I would increase the max pool size and see how high it goes.

Comment: Are there any other systems that use this database, especially reports or ad hoc queries?  All it takes is one long running report with the wrong [isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql) and you could have page/table/index locks that block all of your connections.  Once they are blocked they pile up very quickly. Check the [SQL logs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54494/sql-server-keep-track-of-all-connections-disconnections) for any suspicious users that are not your site.

Comment: exactly, this is the plan. And this is most likely the issue, something starts to load/lock the db and we are still trying to identify the culprit. We couldn't see any long running / heavy queries using the query analyzer (SQL Azure). Locks don't show any active locks when our connections start to pile up (and yes, I'm sure they are piling up very quickly). The only concern is that something starts to load the web app itself and we are verifying this assumption as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *very unlikely* that this is caused by anything other than your application code leaking connections.

Here's a helper library you can use to track when a connection is leaked, and report the call site that initially opened the connection.

http://ssbwcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SsbTransportChannel/SqlConnectionLifetimeTracker.cs

Comment: it's a great suggestion to find connection leak with this kind of helper. I'll definitely try it.

Comment: I've updated my question, I've detected one connection leak which could be probably the cause. Continue my research though

Comment: You found something @AlexeyStrakh? I have the same problem. Web Api 2 + OWIN + Identity. Leak detector shows only registration of ApplicationDbContext in Startup. Web works fine, but in stress test all sql connections are gone in a few seconds.