# SQL connection leaks in OWIN + Identity + Web Api

Tags: sql-server, webforms, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, owin

I have Web Form application with Web Api 2. Whole application is using OWIN and AspNet Identity. So internaly it is Entity Framework 6.

I have standard OWIN registration in startup file

```cs
// Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => ApplicationDbContext.Create(nameOrConnectionString));
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

Managers and DbContext are standard implementations based on MS docs etc. Nothing special.

Web Api controlers are using Basic authentication. For this I have AuthenticationFilter (just some parts of code).

```cs
    public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {

        public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var principal = await AuthenticateInternalAsync(userName, password, cancellationToken);
            if (principal == null)
            {
                // Authentication was attempted but failed. Set ErrorResult to indicate an error.
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid username or password", request);
            }
            else
            {
                // Authentication was attempted and succeeded. Set Principal to the authenticated user.
                context.Principal = principal;
            }
        }

        private static async Task<IPrincipal> AuthenticateInternalAsync(string userName, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Create a ClaimsIdentity with all the claims for this user.
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var applicationUser = await manager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            if (applicationUser == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var signinManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var isAuthenticated = await signinManager.UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(applicationUser, password);
            if (!isAuthenticated)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // ... more code

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            var roles = user.MemberOf.Select(member => member.Name).ToArray();
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);

            return principal;
        }
    }
```

And controlers like

```cs
    [BasicAuthentication] // Enable authentication via an ASP.NET Identity user name and password
    [Authorize]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {

    }
```

It works.

But now I need to do some performance tests using JMeter. When I try to simulate 100+ users, I'll very soon got exception

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> >System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to >obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because of all pooled >connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

There is some connection leak and I'm pretty sure it happens in this BasicAuthentication attribute when Owin and Identity check is used. When attribute is remove, all works fine.

So I did some checks, for example using SqlConnectionLifetimeTracker, so all unclosed connections are from OWIN and CreatePerOwinContext content.

I did other checks, that all IDisposable objects are tried to dispose. Dispose is called on DbContext, UserManager and SignInManager. So it should be ok.

But connections stays open a pool stops working.

Checked using SQL Manager and all 100 sessions are used in sleeping state.

Yes, I know I can increase number of sessions, but it doesn't work. I can set 10000, but in performance test with 500 threads just around 400 sessions is used. Nothing more. But error occured everytime.

Why it happens? Why connections are not closed? And what connections?

Because it is in 3rd party nuget/framework, how can I detect what is wrong and fix it? Is there any way?

Similar problem is here, but no more info
[ADO.NET Pooled connections are unable to reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914648/ado-net-pooled-connections-are-unable-to-reuse/44205546)

EDIT: Add stack trace

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Vypršel časový limit. Časový limit vypršel před získáním připojení od fondu. Pravděpodobným důvodem je využití všech připojení fondu a dosažení maximální velikosti fondu.
   v System.Data.Common.ADP.ExceptionWithStackTrace(Exception e)
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__6`1.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<OpenAsync>d__56.MoveNext()
   --- Konec trasování zásobníku pro vnitřní výjimku ---
   v System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<OpenAsync>d__56.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<EnsureConnectionAsync>d__107.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__156`1.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__6`1.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   v System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   v System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ForEachAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<EnsureRolesLoaded>d__64.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   v CreaSoft.WebAPI.Filters.BasicAuthenticationAttribute.<AuthenticateInternalAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   v CreaSoft.WebAPI.Filters.BasicAuthenticationAttribute.<AuthenticateAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Konec trasování zásobníku z předchozího místa, ze kterého byla vyvolána výjimka ---
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   v System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   v System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Have you tried creating two connection strings in your .config file and configuring AspNet Identity to use one of them? They only need something like `;App=YourApp` and `;App=AspNetIdentity` to differentiate them, making them seperate connection pools. Doing that will allow you to figure out if it's actually a bug in AspNet Identity or if, instead, it's a bug somewhere in your application code.

Comment: Yes, tried to use another connection string just for Owin+Identity. The same problem. Connections jumps up and even not reached Max Pool Size, all starts failing.